# How to store pandas dataframe data to azure blobs using python?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, blob, parquet

I want to store processed data in pandas dataframe to azure blobs in parquet file format. But before uploading to blobs, I have to store it as parquet file in local disk and then upload. I want to write pyarrow.table into pyarrow.parquet.NativeFile and upload it directly. Can anyone help me with this. Below code is working fine:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

battery_pq = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

########  SOme Data Processing

```
battery_pq = pa.Table.from_pandas(battery_pq)
pq.write_table(battery_pq,'example.parquet')
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name,'example.parquet','example.parquet')
```

Need to create the file in memory(I/O file type object) and then upload it to blob.

Comment: To create an in-memory file-object you can use io.BytesIO  https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) for this or alternatively Apache Arrow also provides its native implementation `BufferOutputStream`. The benefit of this is that this writes to the stream without the overhead of going through Python. Thus less copies are made and the GIL is released.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = some pandas.DataFrame
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
buf = pa.BufferOutputStream()
pq.write_table(table, buf)
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(
    container,
    "example.parquet",
    buf.getvalue().to_pybytes()
)
```

Comment: Function [`block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream` ](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.BlockBlobService.create_blob_from_stream) also works for `buf` without getting bytes.

Comment: I don't think that block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes exists in the Python Azure API anymore. Is there a way to do this with the current classes / functions that exist in the API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python

Answer (score 5):

There's a new [python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.aio?view=azure-python) version. `create_blob_from_bytes` is now legacy

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_store_conn_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_path)

parquet_file = BytesIO()
df.to_parquet(parquet_file, engine='pyarrow')
parquet_file.seek(0)  # change the stream position back to the beginning after writing

blob_client.upload_blob(
    data=parquet_file
)
```